# maven assembly get the same md5sum

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I run maven assembly twice for the same sources files and get different md5sum when.

When I open the assembly tar and do md5sum for each files, all the sum are the same. The different only on tar file itself.

The size of tar is equal.

I think that tar itself add some header with time stamp and this is the reason why the sum is different.

Do I have any option/parameter run assembly and get the same md5sum ?

Comment: How does your pom file look like? The exact command ?

Comment: my pom.xml call to assembly plugin ( very simple ) The command is mvn clean install